# Is "to play with one's feet" usable in English?

Tags: expressions

I'm Belgian (Flemish) and over there we have an expression: "met iemands voeten spelen". Google translates it as I would: "Playing with one's feet". Googling around for a minute or so does not give me any results. So I was wondering. Do native English people understand what it means?

In Flemish it means something like: to tease, to joke around, to fool around... not sure if those are correct English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, "playing with one's feet" would be interpreted a meaning literally that; that someone is moving their own feet around in an agitated or fidgety way.  It doesn't have any idiomatic meaning relating to fooling around.

Comment: I guess this is _the_ correct answer.. It is usable, but only if for some reason you mean it literally :)

Answer (score 1):

As a native English (American) speaker I have never heard the phrase used with those meanings. However, to tease, joke around and fool around are all perfectly fine.

Comment: I did some more research and I think I might have found the appropriate expression :)
"to pull someone's leg".. Could this be correct?

Comment: Yes! To pull someone's leg means to tell them something that's exaggerated or not really true in order to trick them in a fun, playful way. It's often an ongoing trick, like letting someone believe something about you for a long time, only to reveal to them later that it was just a joke.